# Weierstrass M-test and Sophomore's Dream.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am trying to prove the Sophomore's Dream $\int_0^1 x^{-x} \ d x = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty n^{-n}$. I get to this point, $\lim\limits_{a \to 0^+} \int_a
^1 \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(x \log x)^n}{n!}  dx$. But in order to interchange the sum and the integral, I need to show that $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(x \log x)^n}{n!}$ converges uniformly. I tried using the M-test, but I don't know how to get
 bounds on the $\big |\frac{(-1)^n(x \log x)^n}{n!} \big |
$. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $|x\log x|\le 1$ for all $x\in(0,1)$.

Comment: I guess my question really just came down to finding a bound for $|x\log x|$ on $(0,1]$, but this is exactly what I'm having a hard time proving formally.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but the graph of the absolute value through me off.

Comment: Still seems like I need a lower bound.

Comment: Wait a minute, on $(0, \frac{1}{2})$, $-x > \log x$.

Comment: hmmm nope this bound does not work - dang it!

Comment: You may in fact prove this by brute force. If $f(x)=x\log x$, then $f(0)=f(1)=0$ (where we extended $f$ continuously in 0) and looking at the first two derivatives shows that $f$ has exactly one local extremum in $(0,1)$ which is a minimum in $x_0=e^{-1}$. Hence, $|f(x)|\le |f(x_0)|= e^{-1} < 1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.